# PHP Replace special characters with corresponding ascii code

Tags: character, ascii

I'm looking for a function that converts all special characters in their corresponding ascii code!
I'll exlpain!

I have this code:

> <trust:RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection xmlns:trust="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512">

And I would like to convert it in

```
%3Ctrust%3ARequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection+xmlns%3Atrust%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oasis-open.org%2Fws-sx%2Fws-trust%2F200512%22%3E
```

If I use the function urlencode it convert the string in

```
%26lt%3Btrust%3ARequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection+xmlns%3Atrust%3D%26quot%3Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oasis-open.org%2Fws-sx%2Fws-trust%2F200512%26quot%3B%3E
```

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was only for 2 characters:
<
"

So I solved with this 3 lines:

```
$result = urlencode($result);
$result = str_replace ('%26lt%3B','%3C', $result);
$result = str_replace ('%26quot%3B','%22', $result);
```